# HttpContext no existe en System.web

Tags: api, .net-5

¡Hola! Estoy realizando [Este tutorial](https://enmilocalfunciona.io/construyendo-una-web-api-rest-segura-con-json-web-token-en-net-parte-ii/) para crear un token de seguridad en un `API`.

El problema que estoy teniendo, es al momento de llamar a la clase `System.Web.HttpContext`, ya que directamente me dice que `HttpContext` no existe en mi contexto actual.

Sé que esta clase proviene de `system.Web`, y que hay unos nugets que me dan esa clase, pero la propiedad en específico que quiero utilizar de ahí es `HttpContext.Current`, que no está en los nugets `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` ni en `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`.

Este es el código con el que estoy trabajando:

```
var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new()
                {
                    ValidAudience = audienceToken,
                    ValidIssuer = issuerToken,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    LifetimeValidator = this.LifetimeValidator,
                    IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
                };

                // Extract and assign Current Principal and user
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken securityToken);
                HttpContext.Current.User = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken); //no reconocido
```

**¿Alguien tiene una idea de qué puede estar pasando?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.current?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0), `HttpContext.Current` no está disponible en `.Net 5`.

En tu caso puede que estés haciendo referencia a otro `HttpContext`, prueba de utilizar `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`.

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309239/cant-access-to-httpcontext-current/18309281) podrás encontrar un poco más de información que te será útil.

Comment: como dato informativo, me funcionó pasando a mi método el HttpContext, y accedí a lo que quería usando un `HttpContext.User`